# "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbstripout.py": /anaconda/bin/python: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, anaconda

**Any advice how to fix the following error message(s)?**

Every time that I am using Terminal with Mac OS Catalina 10.15.1 I get the following output

"/anaconda/bin/python" "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbstripout.py": /anaconda/bin/python: No such file or directory
error: external filter '"/anaconda/bin/python" "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbstripout.py"' failed 127
error: external filter '"/anaconda/bin/python" "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbstripout.py"' failed
fatal: Google Drive/Drive on my xxxx.ipynb: clean filter 'nbstripout' failed

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I moved my git repo. I had to go into `.git/config` and edit the `[diff .ipynb]` section with the updated directory.